# Lebesgue measurable homework problem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. A subset $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is called a hull of $X$ if

1. $E$ is measurable
2. $X \subseteq E$
3. If $F$ is any measurable set such that $X \subseteq F$, then $E$\ $F$ is a zero set

A hull of $X$ should be thought of as a sort of "smallest" measurable set containing $X$.
This is made precise in the problem.

(a) Prove that every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has a hull

(b) Prove that if $E_{1}$ and $E_{2}$ are both hulls of $X$, then $E_{1}$\ $E_{2}$ and $E_{2}$\ $E_{1}$ are zero sets. Thus the hull of $X$ is unique up to zero sets

(c) Let E be a hull of X. Prove that $m(E)=m^{*}(X)$

The hint says to consider the case $m^{*}(X)< \infty$, then consider the case let $R_i=(i,i+1)$ for $i \in \mathbb{Z}$. Let $X_i=X \cap R_i$. Then $X=\cup_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} X_{i} \cup \mathbb{Z}$. I need help to prove this.

Comment: Haven't you posted this question before?

Comment: Yes, but I changed the question this time. I hope someone can help me understand the problem.

Comment: For part (a) can't you just take the intersection of all measurable sets containing $X$?

Comment: Ok, I guess you got this. Since you said it's obvious.

Comment: no, I kind got b, not a.

Comment: For part (b), just apply the third part of the definition with $F:= E_2$, then $F:= E_1$. The 'uniqueness up to a null set' means that the two measurable approximations to $F$ only differ by a null set; and since we 'don't care about null sets', the sets are 'basically the same'.

Comment: could you please show me (a)? I still don't get it.

Comment: (b) is now obvious, should I delete it?

Comment: And I still need help with (c)

Comment: No, I wouldn't delete it, as it gives continuity to the question.

Comment: could please explain more about (a)?

Comment: Have you seen the hints here: http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=3U7tresTD1AC&pg=PA57&lpg=PA57&dq=measurable+hulls+of+sets&source=bl&ots=ZGwBIXGQ07&sig=TrgOugbJwCtPc96RSw71lnRDD9U&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jcU6U6b_LIKqhAfD6oHoBg&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=measurable%20hulls%20of%20sets&f=false

Comment: so how to prove that?

Comment: Look at the hint to Problem 37 in the link I sent. You obtain the $G_k$ there by using the definition of the outer measure (incidentally you have omitted the crucial part of the question that $X$ should have finite outer measure). Then you simply show that $E$ can differ from any measurable $F$ containing $X$ by at most $1/k$ for all $k$, allowing you to conclude that $\mu(E\setminus F) = 0$.

Comment: I will think about (a) more. How about (c)?

Comment: Can I suggest that the term "measurable hull" be added to the title of this question? I know it is at the start of the question, but as this is the main thread I have seen regarding the important topic of measurable hulls, it would be useful to have this clearly labeled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X\subset \mathbb{R}$ with finite measure, then there exist open sets $A_n\supset X$ such that
$$m^*(A_n) - m^*(X) \leq \frac{1}{n}.$$

Define $A = \cap A_n$, then $A$ is measurable and $A\supset X$. To show (c)
$$m^*(A) - m^*(X) \leq m^*(A_n) - m^*(X) \leq \frac{1}{n}$$
for each $n$, we have that $m^*(A) = m^* (X)$.

Let $F\supset X$ be measurable, then
$$m^*(A) = m^*(A\cap F) + m^*(A\cap F^c) \geq m^*(X) + m^*(A\cap F^c)$$
which gives
$$0 \geq m^*(A\cap F^c).$$

For part (b), use the same argument as above, take $F$ to be another Hull of $X$, all the inequality would still work.

For  $X\subset\mathbb{R}$ with $m^*(X) = \infty$, define $X_i = X\cap([-i, -i+1)\cup [i-1, i))$, then $X = \cup_{i=1}^\infty X_i.$ By previous arguement, there exists $A_i$ for each $X_i$, with all $A_i$ disjoint. Define $A = \cup_i A_i$, we see that
$$m^*(A) = \sum_i m^*(A_i) = \sum_i m^*(X_i) \geq m^*(X) = \infty.$$

Comment: There are two cases in part (c). Is (c) based on (a) and (b)?

Comment: (c) is not really based on (a) and (b). You can say (c) is a property that holds when the set $A$ is a hull of $X$.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot, the case I showed is for $\mu(X) < \infty$, can you figure out the rest using the hint in (c)?

Comment: I probably can't figure it out...can you show that part please?

Comment: Why there are two cases and why do we set such X in case 2?

Comment: Are you still there?

Comment: Ok, I am back, the reason you need two cases is that if $m^*(X) = \infty$, then inequality used in the proof $m^*(A) - m^*(X) \leq \frac{1}{n}$ would not make any sense. I will edit a hint for the general case.

Answer (score 3):

**a)**: Hulls occur very often in differents fields of mathematics. Usually, you have some set $M$ which *doesn't* fullfill a particular property (measureable, in this case), and you're looking for the *smallest (in some sense) set which *includes* $M$ and *does* have the desired property. For example, in a vector space, a natural definition for the *hull* of a set of vectors $M$ is the smallest *subspace* with contains $M$. Now, if the *propertery* in question (being a subspace, in the case of vector spaces) is preserved under intersections, then this is easy - just define $$
  \textrm{hull } M := \bigcap_{X \supset M, \textrm{$X$ has desired property}} X \text{.}
$$

The problem in your case is that it's *not* true that the intersection of arbitrary measurable sets is measureable. *But* the intersection of *arbitrarily many* closed sets is closed, and *every* closed set is measurable. So a natural idea for finding the *measurable hull* of an arbitrary set $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ is to set $$
  \textrm{hull } X := \bigcap_{X \subset T \subset \mathbb{R}, \textrm{$T$ closed}} T \text{.}
$$
It's clear that $\textrm{hull } X$ is closed, and hence measurable. What remains to show is that if $F \supset X$ is measurable, $\mu(\textrm{hull } X \setminus F) = 0$. For that, you'll need to use that the closed sets in some way (which, exactly?) *generate* all the measurable sets.

**c)**: If you can show that for the *special* hull constructed in (a) that $m^*(\textrm{hull } X) = m^*(X)$, then the same must hold for any hull $E$ - just invoke (b).

Comment: Intersection of arbitrarily many open sets does not have to be open :P

Comment: @Xiao Ups! Should be *closed*, of course!

Comment: I cannot figure out how to prove  μ(hull X∖F)=0. any hint?

Comment: @user220055 You need to approximate $F$ with a sequence of closed sets...

Comment: I need more explanation...

Comment: @user220055 Look at Xiao's answer... He's using a similar idea, but instead of using closed sets (to allow arbitrary intersections), he uses open sets and only *countable* intersections. The result of that intersection isn't open, but it will be measurable (since $\sigma$-Algebras are closed under countable unions and intersections), which is enough.

Comment: I believe that you have attempted to make the topological closure of a set its measurable hull. This is tempting, but not true. Consider the rationals: their topological closure is the reals.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I keep waking up in the middle of the night with the sense that I've only dreamed the existence of measurable hulls and eventually find my way to this thread, so I would like to provide a more general answer so that I can finally get some sleep.

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a finite measure space, i.e. $\mu(X)<\infty$ (please note that I have made $X$ the space here, not the set we want the hull of, because $X$ is the typical symbol for a general measure space; I hope this doesn't create any confusion). Let $A\subset X$ be any subset, measurable or non-measurable. We want to find a hull of $A$, i.e. a measurable set $E$ containing $A$ with property 3 in the question.

Since $\mu(X)<\infty$,
$$
M:= \inf_{S \in \Sigma,\ A\subset S} \mu(S) < \infty.
$$
Then we can find measurable set $S_1, S_2,\dots$ containing $A$ such that $\mu(S_n)$ decreases to $M$. Let
$$
E = \bigcap_n S_n.
$$
Then $E$ is measurable, $A\subset E$, and since this measure space is finite, we can see that $\mu(E)$ is equal to the infimum. Lastly, suppose $F\supset A$ is also measurable. Then $E\cap F = E \setminus (E\setminus F)$ is also a measurable set containing $A,$ and is also a subset of $E$. Thus $M \leq \mu(E\cap F) \leq \mu(E) = M,$ so it follows that $\mu(E\setminus F) = 0$. Therefore, $E$ satisfies all the desired properties of a measurable hull.

This can be extended to $\sigma$-finite spaces, which are measure spaces $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ in which $X$ written as a countable union of sets $Y_n$ of finite measure, even if $\mu(X)=\infty$. To find a hull in this case, we simply intersect $A$ with each $Y_n$ $X$, and a hull for the intersection in each $Y_n$, and then take the union. To check that property 3 is satisfied, remember that a countable union of sets of measure $0$ has measure $0$.

$\mathbb{R}$ with the Lebesgue measure is $\sigma$-finite (think along the lines of the hint in the problem), so this concludes the proof. Notice, though, that I never mentioned the Lebesgue outer measure. This might be disconcerting, because with a measure constructed from an outer measure, it seems just as good to define your hull to be a measurable set $E$ containing $A$ such that $\mu^*(A) = \mu(E)$, and with the properties above (in this case, property 3 is needed only to deal with sets of infinite outer measure). However, consider the way in which the hull I found and the outer measure are both defined using infima. This should show you how to prove that the definitions in this case are equivalent.